# Data modelling of raw data for further transformation in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, time-series, nosql

I am working on a system for storing and processing time series data from a couple of plants. Every plant has a different number of raw measurement values, each of them represented as a key-value pair.

The raw data needs to be preprocessed to obtain semantics. I also need to save the raw data, because the transformation process should be configurable. While I am new to No-Sql databases and Cassandra I searched for resources on the web and found the [weather station example](http://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling) (similar described on other resources, too).

My requirements are similar to this example, but as extension I need a way to store a variable number of measurement values (key-pair) per plant. I also know, that my table model highly depends on the queries I want to run against it. The most common queries will be:

- Get all values per key for a specific time (range) and plant.
- Get all values per multiple keys for a specific time (range) and plant.

My question now is, how would a table structure look like that best fit theses requirements?

I thought about something like that, but don't know if it contains some drawbacks:

```
CREATE TABLE values_per_day (
  plant_id text,
  date text,
  event_time timestamp,
  key text,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((plant_id, date), event_time, address)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation for Cassandra is to start with the queries you want to perform. For each query, consider the inputs to the query, which indicate what data you want it to return. For each query you should have a table that has the inputs to the query as its primary key. If you want to query for a rangeof values, that value should be the cluster key (not the partition key) of a primary key, with the other inputs the partition key. If you want to query for very long value ranges, consider slicing that value into buckets.